# Print Sum of Array

Tags: python, arrays, sum

```
import math

import os

import random

import re

import sys


def simpleArraySum(ar_count,ar):
    if ar_count == len(ar):
         print(sum(ar))
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    ar_count = int(input().strip())

    ar = list(map(int,input().rstrip().split()))

    result = simpleArraySum(ar_count,ar)

    fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

I am trying to print sum of values in an array in python. I am trying to solve this on a coding platform but it does not print any value.
Why my code is not giving any kind of Output???

Comment: That's a string.

Comment: Remove the `'''` at the beginning and at the end of your file

Comment: I assumed OP meant to use ``` instead of ''' and fixed it.  The problem is that `simpleArraySum` doesn't return a value.  It just prints its result, but then returns `None`.   You need to return the sum, not print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try return instead of printing the outputs.

```
def simpleArraySum(ar_count,ar):
    if ar_count == len(ar):
         return sum(ar)
    else:
        return "Invalid Input"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `simpleArraySum` method doesn't have a return statement. It's only printing. You need a return statement in there for `result` to get something.